# Should I make one table for 80 columns?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I have a situation in which I have 80 columns for the table. I can divide this table into multiple tables. But i don't have a reason to do so. Now I want to know if is it good practice to make a table with 80 columns?
Columns are boolean values mostly yes/no .

Comment: *Columns are boolean values mostly yes/no.* Each 64 "flag" columns (where the only possible values are 0/1 or 0/1/NULL) may be compacted into one column of SET datatype.

Comment: 80 columns sounds like a lot and probably you should look into normalising your data, however this is impossible to answer without knowing more about the table, the data and its intended use. You may find you have a reason to do so months down the line due to query performance or data growth or any other number of reasons.